# kill adb opened with subprocess.popen in python

Tags: python, subprocess, adb, pid, kill

I need to run a command adb get-state from my python library.

I used

```
subprocess.popen
```

to execute the command and killed the process using pid.

If the adb daemon is not in running state, adb process will create an extra adb process and terminate the first process created after starting the daemon (even manually its the same).

Hence I am not able to kill the adb process opened by subprocess open since it has the pid of the first adb process (which has already terminated)

Is there any way I can kill the real adb process which executes the command from python.

Comment: you mean kill the process and all its subprocesses then?

Comment: yes I guess so...

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you yo kill all the running processes of adb before starting a new one . Here is some sample code that can kill already running process under windows environment.

This code Kills any adb process that is already running and then opens a new process daemon for adb

Sample Code :

```
import subprocess
import os
p = subprocess.Popen("tasklist", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

RunningProcessLIst = p.stdout.readlines()
print("Kill all running instances of adb.exe")
for runningPro in RunningProcessLIst :
    if "adb.exe" in str(runningPro) :

        os.system("taskkill /F /IM adb.exe")




process =subprocess.Popen("I:\\adb\\Win32\\adb.exe adb get-state") # you subprocesses call will be here
```

Hope this helps

Comment: but this might effect other programs which use adb right?!

Comment: I believe you cannot run multiple instances of adb on same machine so no point in keep process alive as all adb servers are using the same port for binding. So the code should work for you.